# Dojo: identifying dijit tree nodes with css selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

Is there any way to select a group of nodes in a dijit tree having some property/flag?

Alternatively, can I add a CSS selector to those nodes so I can do operations on all of them in one go?

I understand dojo.query() can help with the selection part but how do I apply the selectors in the first place>

I tried adding a 'span' in the 'name' attribute of the json array(my data source) but it is parsed as text instead of a DOM object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can select them based on the path they are in, look at the documentation in http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Tree-examples.html

```
mytree.set('paths', [ ['world', 'AF', 'KE', 'Nairobi'], ['world', 'SA'] ] );
```